# type duplication problem qraphql typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql

```js
@ObjectType()
export class GraphqlUserRegisterResponseType {
  @Field(() => String)
  resultCode: ResultCode
  @Field()
  message: string
  @Field()
  data: GraphqlUserRegisterResponseDataType
}
```

I use this type of response for every request. But I have to duplicate it, since the type of `data` is different in all the answers. How to avoid duplication?

Answer (score 0):

[generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) to the rescue

```
class GraphqlUserRegisterResponseType<D> {
  resultCode: ResultCode
  message: string
  data: D
}

interface CreateSomethingResponseData{
    name: string
    result: string
    status: number
}
const resp = new GraphqlUserRegisterResponseType<CreateSomethingResponseData>()

resp.data.name
```

so you defining a single interface/type/class for response and then define multiple types for `data`. Then use one of them with this common response class

Comment: A type is a class with a decorator, I can only use a class with `@ObjectType` as a type. Maybe I don't understand how the `graphql-type` library works

Comment: Decorators should work just fine with this solution. The idea is to use generic for `data` because it's type is not known in advance